# pip package dependency problem

Tags: python, package, pip

take this as example: https://github.com/bitprophet/fabric/blob/master/setup.py#L41

so Fabric requires pycrypto >= 1.9 and paramiko >=1.7.6

what if pycrypto update version to 2.1, and change their api, it will affect my package. this is not the result i want.

so is their a convention that, package can't change api, or is it posible to wrap the package i needed into my own package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about [this](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html#requirements-files)?

an excerpt

> So what are requirements files? They are very simple: lists of packages to install. Instead of running something like pip MyApp and getting whatever libraries come along, you can create a requirements file something like:

```
MyApp
Framework==0.9.4
Library>=0.2
```

> Then, regardless of what MyApp lists in setup.py, you’ll get a specific version of Framework (0.9.4) and at least the 0.2 version of Library. (You might think you could list these specific versions in MyApp’s setup.py – but if you do that you’ll have to edit MyApp if you want to try a new version of Framework, or release a new version of MyApp if you determine that Library 0.3 doesn’t work with your application.) You can also add optional libraries and support tools that MyApp doesn’t strictly require, giving people a set of recommended libraries.